# Site Map in asp.net not worked with Login page

Tags: asp.net

I have this Site map:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="SiteMapHolder" runat="server">
    <!-- ===================== Site Map ======================= -->
        <div id="SiteMapTD"  class="SiteMap">
                            <asp:SiteMapPath id="SiteMapPath" runat="server" pathseparator="/">
                            <PathSeparatorStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#800000" />
                            <CurrentNodeStyle ForeColor="#000000" />
                            <NodeStyle Font-Names="Palatino linotype" Font-Size="16px" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#800000" />
                            <RootNodeStyle Font-Names="Palatino linotype" Font-Size="16px" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#800000" />
                        </asp:SiteMapPath>
                    </div>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Which works just fine, in all pages except of Login page.
When I'm getting into this page the site map content is blank.
And here is the `Web.sitemap` configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0"  >
    <siteMapNode url="~/Default.aspx" title="ΑΡΧΙΚΗ ΣΕΛΙΔΑ">
    <siteMapNode url="~/Account/Login.aspx" title="Είσοδος" >
      <siteMapNode url="~/Account/Register.aspx" title="Εγγραφή" />
    </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>    
</siteMap>
```

Is there some one who knows why that happen? 

 
**Additional Update** 

Looking with the `Inspect Element` I see this in Login.aspx file, notice that the Login is not displayed at all

```
outerText: "↵Login↵Παρακαλώ περάστε το όνομα χρήστη και τον κωδικό
```

And in the other hand I have another behavior in the Register.aspx

```
outerText: "Start Page/SignIn↵Νέος Λογαριασμός↵Χρησιμοποιέστε
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank you very much for your efforts to assist me on this issue.
But from what I've seen there is no any solution on it except to start a new Web Site from scratch.
An that is what I do and all the previous issues are vanished and right now I'm in the write new User Handling
NOT from the standard Membership provider, but I'm creating one of my own and manipulating the User Data as my Web Site needs to, No more, No less.
Thanks again...
See you in my next post.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you don't have any Content control in your Login page with `ContentPlaceHolderID="SiteMapHolder"`. i.e. Your `Login.aspx` page should NOT contain the below line:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" 
     ContentPlaceHolderID="SiteMapHolder">
```

The Content control on your `login` page will overwrite the default content you defined in your Master file using: `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="SiteMapHolder" runat="server">`

Comment: I don't have such of lines in my Login.aspx file